# Are drop-catches and stumping-failures recorded for official statistics?

Tags: cricket, trivia, statistics, records

Are drop-catches and stumping-failures recorded for official statistics ?

This type of records will help in knowing who is a better bowler, in a bad team of fielders or wicketkeepers.

Eg : Consider a very good bowler B1, who can easily fool the batsmen so that the wicket-keeper can stump-out or catch-behind; but the wicket-keeper is not "talented", so the batsmen escape. Also, bowler changes his pace such that fielders can get catches easily, but they drop most of it.

Consider a very bad bowler (or an average bowler) B2 with a great wicket-keeper who never misses opportunities for stump-out or catch-behind. Also the fielders are too good, such that they stretch and jump beyond reasonable limits to convert sixes to caught-outs.

When the records are compared, bowler B1 will look very bad, while bowler B2 will look very good. To high-light this type of issue , records (statistics) of drop-catches and stumping-failures will be very helpful. Eg For making "World XI teams" or "Dream teams".

Comment: Additional ask : Any known cases of such good bowlers in bad teams ? I know of many teams with great wicket-keepers and great fielders.

Comment: Question: is [James Foster](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england/content/player/12877.html) a bad keeper because he misses stumpings? Or is it actually a *really good* keeper because he stands up to bowlers which most keepers would be standing back to? Similar stuff applies to fielders. You probably want to look into the research done by the baseball stats heads on this sort of thing before claiming that simplistic statistics like "missed stumpings" are actually a good predictor of *anything*.

Comment: @PhilipKendall , I am not claiming anything. I only want more information before I claim anything. The information I want is related to "drop-catches & stumping-failures". For reference , here ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_%28cricket%29#Penalty_runs ) it says that "Since the 1980s a no ball has been scored against the bowler, making the bowling statistics **more accurate**" which implies that, previously it was "**less accurate**". I think tracking the missed wickets is also a consideration (for or against the bowler), but we will know that only after it is recorded for a few years.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen an instance of dropped catches or missed stumpings being recorded in official statistics. They may be written into scorebooks as "incidents" or further annotations, but I don't believe they're recorded specifically.

Looking at Cricinfo's Statsguru [Test Bowling](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;type=bowling) I don't see an ability to search by those items, which would lead me to believe they're not available.

Answer (score -1):

> Unfortunately there is no such tool to calculate failures not only in
>   the case of fielders but also in the case of bowlers and batsman

But we can get stats of team failures like lowest total made by the team,highest margin of loss,etc.

> But I believe all this faults will be identified and noted by team
>   coach or some other officials responsible for the team.

Sometimes you can even come through that the head coach sitting in pavilion   writing some points while the game is going on (whether it is good or bad).

> So by considering the points noted by coach for the matches the under performed players will be sacked.

---

> PS: Though there are no official stats to identify player's failure
>   but still you can find them in some private sites or in facebook pages
>   all this stats are been listed by anti fans of that player too boo
>   him/ his fans with such stats.